# Telerik Grid arbitrary fields

Tags: angular, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I need to be albe to edit multiple values in a grid

Say

"Type" is a combo
"Size" is a float
"Name" is a string

I need "Type", "Size", "Name" in the first column; and in the second I need a dropdown (Type), then a numeric editor (Size) and finally a text editor for the "Name".

I try to implement something similar to that

[image]

having heterogenous data in a column, so, impossible to have a template for the elements of the column

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to supply editors for cells that correspond to the field names that you have. For instance, if you have "Type", the Name of the DropDownList has to be "Type".

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("Type")
    // other options
)
```

You could specify all of the needed editors in separate cshtml files inside the EditorTemplates folder and reference them via the EditorTemplateName option of the column:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.FieldName).EditorTemplateName("<<editor name goes here>>");
```

The grid will take care of the binding part. For the complex ones, you might have to specify "data-bind" attributes.

Comment: the problem is that a column does not have an unique template, every cell in the column is heterogenous one

Comment: also, is not about the DropDownList as itself, but about a grid Cell as dropdownList